# Keep getting errors opening converted python file to .exe

Tags: python

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7ZWU.png)

I've had the same problem with sounddevice, telling me there was no module named sounddevice. The python file works fine in pycharm, as well as converting it, but upon opening the .exe I get this error.

Comment: Have you tried checking out that module which the error talks about?

Comment: How are you creating the exe?  If you `import win32clipboard`, then most of the exe creators should capture that.  If not, you may need to create a config file to tell it to do so.

Comment: @TimRoberts I used auto-py-to-exe. The first problem I encountered was sounddevice being a missing module, when I already imported it in pycharm. I fixed that by importing it on my cmd , but cant with win32clipboard

Comment: @CamiloMartínez I have tried importing the module in terminal with pip install, but I just got an error saying "ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement win32clipboard (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for win32clipboard"